# Hot reload not working in VUE3 and tailwind

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, hot-reload

Hot reload is not working in Vue3 and tailwind application.

If I am changing the code(using vscode editor) and respective data is not changed in the browser. I need to logout and login again to see the new changes.

My package.json

```
"vue": "^3.0.0"
"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
"tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.1.2"
```

Please help me how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: More information is required. It could be related to Vite or webpack configuration.